# Proof: $ M=\{x\in \Bbb{R}|\exists n \in \Bbb{N},\forall m \in \Bbb{N}( m \geq n\to a(m)\leq x)\}$ is bounded below

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need the proof of the following:

- ***Prop.***: let be $a \in \Bbb{R}^\Bbb{N}$, and $a$ is bounded above, then: $$ M=\{x\in \Bbb{R}|\exists n \in \Bbb{N},\forall m \in \Bbb{N}( m \geq n \to a(m)\leq x)\} \mbox{ is  bounded below}$$

Comment: @Git Gud: $a$ is obviously a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: @user2345215 Right, i thought it was $\mathbb R^N$, misread it.

Comment: @Гарнак Олэговытц Your question was fine, it was me who misread it.

Comment: @GitGud, ok thanks! :)

Comment: Is this true? If we set $a(n)=-n$, which is bounded from above, we have $a_m=-m\leq-n=a_n\leq x$ for all $m\geq n$ and sufficiently high $n$. So it's true for all real $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example which shows your question is wrong:

Define $a:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$  with $a(n)=-n$. Then for any $n\in\Bbb{N}$ we have $a(n)\leq0$. If $x\in\Bbb{R}$ be an arbitrary negative number then by choosing $n>|x|$ we have for any $m\geq n$, $a(m)=-m\leq -n\leq x$. So we conclude  $x\in M$, that means $(-\infty,0]\subset M$ and consequently $M$ is unbounded below.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a proof of that every bounded above sequence has a lim sup. That's obviously false, as user2345215 has noted. Perhaps you have forgotten any condition (like the sequence being increasing, or also below bounded)?